# How to get a string of a query created using Python's gql.dsl module

Tags: python, gql

fairly new to gql in Python, and I've been working on creating some queries using the dsl module. I am currently running into an issue with a query I've created, and I was wondering if there were any easy way to view the string of the dsl query the gql library is sending to the specified server? I am unable to use any external tools to view the communication between my client and the server, so the solution would have to be in Python. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think the author asked about how to visualize a graphql query in text constructed by dsl. DSLQuery (https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/dsl_module.html) can be executed by gql client but I couldn't find a way to just print the graphql query in text for debugging purposes.

Comment: I posted an answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I found a following solution, you can use print_ast:

```
from graphql import print_ast
from gql.dsl import DSLSchema, dsl_gql

query = dsl_gql(
       DSLQuery(
           ds.Query.hero.select(
              ds.Character.id,
              ds.Character.name,
              ds.Character.friends.select(ds.Character.name),
              )
         )
      )

raw_query_string = print_ast(query)

# Print the GraphQL query

print(raw_query_string)
```